# restart plesks (v 10.3.1) iptables rules from console

Tags: firewall, plesk

I'm using Plesk 10.3.1.
I have some settings made in the Plesk Firewall Tool:

The Plesk Panel (port 8443) is only accessable from defined IPs.
SSH is open for all (not for root and on an ohter port)

Now, when I have an IP which is not allow for plesk panel I cant login.
So I connect to SSH and want add my current IP to the iptables rules, how to do that
or where is the needed file?

how can I edit (where is the file?) and restart the current iptables rules generated with the plesk firewall script/tool in the console?

plesk 10.3 dont use /etc/sysconfig/iptables file, this is empty or only has standard config ...

best,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what little I know, Plesk stores the firewall configuration in `/sbin/iptables` for Ubuntu.

I followed this [Firewall logging tutorial](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/how-to-add-logging-to-the-plesk-firewall/) which explains how to add a new iptables set of rules.

I'm wary to give you specific advice as you can knacker yourself very quickly with iptables.

However running `$ /sbin/iptables --line-numbers -nL` is a good place to start which will show you the existing iptables rules that you have.